# How to make function to load all highscore from database mysql using php?

Tags: php, mysql

ScoreBoard database table:

[image]

here is my code

```
function getScoreROOM($simpanIDR,$conn){
    $sql = "SELECT userName, totalScore FROM ScoreBoard WHERE gameId='$simpanIDR' LIMIT 5";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    return "{$row['userName']} : {$row['totalScore']}";
    mysqli_free_result($result);

}
```

the  output code above just showing one row from database table ScoreBoard. and i want to show all userName and totalScore from all row where has the same gameId.

any solution? thnks

Comment: what does the `print_r` or `var_dump` of $result show ?

Comment: what charset are you using for the `gameid`? it's probably not `utf8_bin` but you may want to use that.  Normally the DB is case insensitive, so in `rare` cases you could match the wrong hash...  That said, the binary charset is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return all rows from the result with `while` loop:

```
function getScoreROOM($simpanIDR,$conn){
    $sql = "SELECT userName, totalScore FROM ScoreBoard WHERE gameId='$simpanIDR' LIMIT 5";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $data = [];
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
       $data[]  = "{$row['userName']} : {$row['totalScore']}";
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);

    return $data;
}
```

Somewhere else you can iterate over results and output data.

Comment: wow it is works for the function. thank u so much. btw, it is possible to use 'for loop' to iterate the array return $data?

Comment: Sure, it is possible. Use `for` or `foreach`, which you like.